# trigger a 12 hours loop

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm not sure how to proper name the question. Please fell free do edit.

I have a background console application running on my server. The console application send emails and do minor stuff from time to time (each 5 minutes).

The application it's not started every 5 minutes via task manager, it's opened once in the install process and a infinite loop and thread.sleep keep it running. Because of that I can't configure the task manager to open the application using a specific parameter.

Now I need to add a task to run every 12 hours, and I want to use the same application. The task consists in delete and create a few files, but check if there's 12 hours since the last creation based on the files date every 5 minutes looks a bit unwise for me.

Is there a non expensive way (no database, no log, no file creation date, no multi thread) to tick a 12 hours loop using the same application I have? If not, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: You might look at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Or you could just remember the last time you ran, and check if it was 12 hours ago every time your 5 minute task tuns.

Comment: Ever consider running it as a service? I know it doesn't answer your question - Option for Original Question - create two threads - each with their own timer object - and have the timers set specific for each task. If done correctly - you can always extend to a 3rd / 4th one later.  Just be cautious of using shared resources between the two threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an efficient means of scheduling at midnight utc without looping:

```
var now=DateTime.UtcNow;
var today=now.Date;
var tomorrow=today.AddDays(1);
var dueTime=tomorrow-now;

System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
timer = new Timer(_ => {
    try
    {
        //do your thing
    }
    finally
    {
        timer.Dispose();
    }
},null,dueTime,TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1d))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the Windows Task Scheduler is for. There's no point reinventing something that already exists.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you already have a loop that waits 5 minutes and then does task A. Now you want to add task B to be run every 12 hours. I would either replace both with Timer objects, or every 5 minutes when task A runs, check to see how long since task B has run. If its at least 12 hours then run task B. Something along the lines of

```
if (last12HourRun.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalHours > 12)
  // run task B
  last12HourRun = DateTime.Now;
```